# Double Nat Detection

Tags: nat, traceroute

I am trying to figure out if I have double NAT so I ran some `traceroute`.

First I set my router in NAT mode and ran `traceroute 8.8.8.8`
Here the result

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  testwifi.here (192.168.86.1)  1.305 ms  1.289 ms  2.580 ms
2  10.105.104.1 (10.105.104.1)  13.437 ms  13.443 ms  13.439 ms
3  192.168.105.1 (192.168.105.1)  5.190 ms  5.445 ms  5.446 ms
4  66.71.224.1 (66.71.224.1)  5.456 ms  5.454 ms  5.462 ms
5  xe-2-3-1.er2.ord2.us.zip.zayo.com (64.124.178.57)  5.459 ms  5.466 ms 5.462 ms
6  ae9.cs3.ord2.us.eth.zayo.com (64.125.27.214)  5.507 ms * *
7  * * *
8  74.125.50.194 (74.125.50.194)  3.064 ms  3.082 ms  3.079 ms
9  108.170.243.193 (108.170.243.193)  3.075 ms  3.639 ms  3.648 ms
10  108.170.233.111 (108.170.233.111)  4.409 ms 216.239.42.109 (216.239.42.109)  4.414 ms 216.239.42.113 (216.239.42.113)  2.459 ms
11  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  2.940 ms  2.943 ms  2.938 ms
```

And then only in AP mode, just as a bridge. Here the result:

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (10.105.104.1)  4.989 ms  4.871 ms  4.830 ms
 2  192.168.105.1 (192.168.105.1)  4.680 ms  4.654 ms  4.566 ms
 3  66.71.224.1 (66.71.224.1)  4.599 ms  4.882 ms  4.863 ms
 4  xe-2-3-1.er2.ord2.us.zip.zayo.com (64.124.178.57)  4.847 ms  4.774 ms  4.735 ms
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  74.125.50.194 (74.125.50.194)  3.142 ms  3.126 ms  3.068 ms
 8  108.170.243.174 (108.170.243.174)  4.396 ms 108.170.243.225 (108.170.243.225)  4.289 ms 108.170.243.193 (108.170.243.193)  2.044 ms
 9  216.239.42.109 (216.239.42.109)  1.991 ms 72.14.232.169 (72.14.232.169)  1.927 ms 108.170.238.91 (108.170.238.91)  2.240 ms
10  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  1.859 ms  2.086 ms  2.058 ms
```

Looking at this results, I don't understand why I have three private IPs in the first run. If I had double NAT I was only expecting two.
In the second run, I only have two because the Private IP produced by the router is not present.

This means I have "triple" NAT? How can I solve this?

Thank you very much,
Marco

Comment: *I don't understand why I have three private IPs in the first run. If I had double NAT I was only expecting two.* The 3rd seems to be your ISP inner private subnet address.

Comment: *How can I solve this?* Buy "real IP" service.

Comment: For the record, going through multiple gateways with private IP addresses doesn't necessarily means going through that many times of NAT, even though that might be likely the case.

Comment: @Akina, what do you mean with "buy real IP service"?

Comment: Yes. But I'd recommend you to consult with your ISP. Explain them why multi-NAT is not safe for you for to be sure that real IP service in their form will solve your task.